# Three-Dimensional (or more) Tagging System? PHP / MySQL Database Architecture

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, tagging

I come forth bearing, rather obviously, a brain-stormy question. That, or I'm just too much of a noob to see any obvious answers to it:

How can I achieve a tagging system in which each tag has a specific relationship to each user of a website?

A very plain example of what I'm trying to achieve would be a situation in which the system keeps track of page-hits a user makes for each tag. For example, multiple tag keywords are "tagged" to every page of the website. A page about environmental science might be tagged with keywords like "biology" and "sociology". When User A visits that page, a number is incremented by 1 that counts each time User A has viewed "biology", and another count for "sociology".

Thus, we end up with records that exhibit how much a person likes a particular tag.

What would be the most efficient way to do this with MySQL and would it be possible to work it into a two-table system such as the following?

```
Table 1: Tags

 - tag_title
 - tagged_pages
 - user_likes

Table 2: Users

 - user_id
```

Adding more table columns is completely fine. What I'm trying to avoid is duplicating the tags table and all the records in it.

All that I've come up with so far is having the `user_likes` field be formatted something like this for each tag: `101-12, 99-3, 156-14`...etc. Then using PHP explode() to separate the user_id from the number of likes.

Thanks a lot for your creative insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever put more than one information in a column. It's the first rule of normalization and you really shouldn't break it.

I think you need some more tables to correctly build this (and have it normalized correctly)

```
users
    id
    name

tags
    id
    name

pages
    id

page_tags
    page_id
    tag_id

user_page_hits
    user_id
    page_id
    hits
```

Now, if you want to know how much a user likes a certain tag, you can create a VIEW on those tables like

```
user_tag_hits
    as select u.name, t.name, sum(uph.hits) hits from users u
              join user_page_hits uph on uph.user_id = u.id
              join page_tags pt on pt.page_id = uph.page_id
              join tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id
              group by u.name, t.name
```

Which would produce results like

```
username tagname  hits
me  tag1    112
me  tag2    112
me  tag3    70
me  tag4    4
me  tag5    4
```

Comment: But wouldn't this create exponentially large amounts of records in the  page_tags table? There would be many many repeats of both tags and tables. It would grow larger an more complex with abilities to have more complex relationships between users and tags than just page-hits. I understand that there shouldn't be more than one information in a cell, but is there no better way to do it? "Three-dimensionally"?

Comment: Databases were MADE so they could hold millions and billions of data in tables, and with multi-dimensional relational links between them. This is exactly what these tools you use were created for. I mean, even if you are talking about a billion entries, every one of them is extremely small. Two integers, that's 64bit of space. Times a billion, you get about 7 TiB of data, which really isn't that much nowadays. And with proper indexing, you will probably not feel any difference in speed when querying 100 entries compared to 1.000.000 entries.